# Question regarding Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Show that if $ f \in L^1[(0,2\pi)]$ and $\sum^\infty_{-\infty} |\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty$ then $f \in L^2[(0,2\pi)]$

where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the Fourier transform

I started by by substituting the inverse transform into $||f||_2$, but it isnt going anywhere.

Will anyone give me some help?

Comment: Do you know that the Fourier transform is a unitary isomorphism of $L^2$?

Comment: are you referring to Plancherel theorem or parsevels identity?

Comment: The Plancherel theorem.

Comment: but doesnt Plancherel theorem requires $f$ to be in both $L^1$ and $L^2$

Comment: The sketch I have in mind is that since you know $g = \hat{f}\in L^2$, and you know by Plancherel that the Fourier transform can be extended to a unitary operator $L^2\to L^2$, the inverse Fourier transform of $g$ is also in $L^2$. Then I want to argue that $g = f$ and this implies $f\in L^2$. (I haven't checked details if this works, though, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer.)